# Mule ESB Community Standalone Runtime

Tags: mule

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to use community Runtime of Mule ESB with out any trail? If so, can you please provide me the link to download the community Runtime. I googled it, but couldn't find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find Mule community edition standalone here :- https://developer.mulesoft.com/download-mule-esb-runtime

And yes you can use the community edition standalone without any restriction

Comment: thank you, it has become increasingly difficult to find this link since mulesoft.org became developer.mulesoft.com

Comment: Hi Anirban I have downloaded Mule standalone 3.8.1 CE, but some of the features are not working in it but works in 3.8.4 EE like transform message. Do you have any idea how to use transform message in CE.

Comment: Transform message is an enterprise edition feature and not available in CE

Comment: Can you configure the "Mule standalone runtime" that is available on this download page to use Community Edition? In AnyPoint Studio you can download the Community Runtime, but not sure how to configure/deploy without Studio.

Comment: The download link targets to community edition. You don't need to configure anything

Answer (score -1):

https://www.mulesoft.com/lp/dl/mule-esb-enterprise
Included in the trial:
• Connect data to apps or build APIs graphically on your laptop with Anypoint
• Studio
• Jumpstart your project with a rich library of prebuilt connectors and templates
• Test and debug your applications with the Mule ESB runtime embedded in
• Studio
• Deploy applications on-premises or to CloudHub, MuleSoft’s iPaaS
• Manage and monitor deployments through a central dashboard